# Avoid short sections at the end of page

Tags: page-breaking, lyx, document-configuration

I am using `LyX` and try to avoid the occurence of short text sections at the end of a page which start with a chapter/section etc. Is it possible to add a preamble line which can tell LyX that if a section only has less than e.g. 3 lines in the bottom of a page, it should be moved to the next page?

The way I solve this at the moment is to wait until my report is finished and then add `\newpage` where this occurs, but it's starting to bug me since I have quite large reports and feel that I loose a bit of control over the documents structure.

Here's an example: [MWE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/elc2e0khyfuzbbt/mwe.lyx)

[image: excerpt from generated pdf]

Comment: Anything that needs to be zipped up does not qualify as a MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that. Edited to just be the .lyx file. Thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean lines and not sentences, you should be able to do this with the [`needspace`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/needspace) package. The concept is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\needspace{6\baselineskip}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-4]
An extra line

A second extra line

\needspace{6\baselineskip}
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

In this case if there is not 6 baselineskips worth of space, the section gets moved to a new page (I chose 6 so I did not have to fiddle with the spacing to get things to move). It is not a perfect solution since I needed to add two lines to get the section to jump and not a single line.

You should be able to modify `\section` (and maybe `\subsection` etc) to include `\needspace`.